# Why TAB swipe reload content?

Tags: android

I have 4 tabs, first with grid view of photos and three without anything content, why when i swipe from first to three or four tab and return to first all my grid reload data from server, how to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try to set your method `setOffscreenPageLimit()` of PageViewer

```
viewPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

How setOffScreenPageLimit works:

> When you use the default implementation of setOffscreenPageLimit() it is only loading the one fragment which is to the right of it. For eg. when you are on index 1, it has index 2 loaded in memory but not index 0, so swiping left will have to generate a new fragment from scratch.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please mark correct if it helped you.